# how do you create a meta-strip (group of strips) in the VSE using python?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I want to use python to create a series of strips and group them into a meta-strip.  I have noticed there are several new_ methods on scene.sequence_editor.sequences such as new_clip(), new_effect(), new_image(), new_mask(), new_movie(), new_scene(), new_sound() but there is not one for the meta-strip.

What is the proper API to use to create a meta strip from several other strips?

```
def make_meta(scn, strip_list):
    # magic goes here

strip_list = make_parts(scn)
make_meta(scn, strip_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be no low-level RNA method to create or make a meta strip, but you can still use the operator:

```
bpy.ops.sequencer.meta_make()
```

Make sure you select all relevant strips before you call it.

Comment: Although I hate the awkwardness of using anything from bpy.ops, I was able to make it work (in the tail end of make_strip_from() at http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/create-vse-image-strips.html )

Comment: Wondering if there's a better way to do this by now.